# Is it possible to develop iOS apps on Windows if I own a mac?

Tags: macos, mac, ios

I own a mac, but I'd like to use my PC/windows as my primary development device.

Is it possible to write software on Windows and use the Mac to compile/build/sign/deploy?

I know I can remote in, but that is awfully slow.

Comment: Have you checked out the new .Net Core? I believe .Net Core can be installed on Mac and allow programs (developed on the version of .net) to be executed and run on a Mac or Linux device. Microsoft made .Net ope source and Cross-platform. .Net Core is the first iteration, I believe.

Comment: Furthermore, Java can be run cross platform due to it's JVM execution.

Comment: I want to code in swift or objective C

Comment: I'm not sure about that then...

Answer (score 0):

It has been done.  Just Googling for it, I found this article on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine) that explains how to do it.

Just glancing at it, it looks like there is come commercial software you might have to purchase in order to do it.

Comment: Seems like these solutions involve installing a VM, or cross-compiling c#. I want to write Swift/objective-c on windows, and built using my mac.